# How to overwrite the development branch with the master branch history

Tags: git, branch

### Problem

In our workflow we have a development branch which becomes littered with features from time to time. Sometimes those features will never be merged to master because they won't work or the feature has been dropped.

Therefore the development branch consists of unneccessary commits.

Every half a year we try do *recreate* the development branch. We remove it and check it out from our actual master branch.
Every developer needs to be aware of this event because they have to switch their local development branch with the newly created origin/development.

Often enough this just does not work. Because some developers are ill or on vacation and as they return they skip the email describing this event. They end up with confusion.

### Question

How can we kind of cleanse the **development** branch to only have those commits that are equal to the **master** branch. Actually it should contain the same commit history as when we would freshly check it out from the master branch.

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite the history of the `development` branch to arbitrarily point to the same commit `master` does, from which point they would have exactly identical history.

```
git branch -f development master
```

However, since `development` is shared, it means that every repo user will have to update its now-obsolete local version of `development`, and this means conflict resolving... hard to say it'll be any more convenient that the workflow you described.

Comment: Yeah well I am really craving for an approach that has the least inconvenients regarding for developers to be aware of the changes. Best thing would be nothing would change for them when pushing. But that does not makes sense since they surely would push the ol' dirty branch again eh?

Answer (score 0):

> Actually it should contain the same commit history as when we would freshly check it out from the master branch.

If you really want the `development` branch to be identical to the `master` branch, then you may reset it:

```
git checkout development
git reset --hard master
```

But this isn't really an ideal thing to do, because it rewrites the history of the `development` branch.  Ss you said, some developers might be on vacation and would get a surprise when they come back and pull `development`.  Actually, *every* developer would get hosed, except for the one developer who does the hard reset.

So, a better plan would be to create a *new* development branch (with a different name), whose starting point is the `master` branch.  Then, each developer may simply checkout this branch fresh from the start, without any issues.